# p3dx gazebo problem with Fuerte

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite new in ROS. I simulated pioneer3dx with gazebo by doing some modifications and downloading the set of packages by
`sudo apt-get install ros-electric-erratic-robot`
to use erratic robot's teleop.

Now, there is another laptop with Fuerte version and I want to do the same thing on it, but it seems impossible in this way, and downloading erratic_robot package alone gives some errors because of some missing files. Can you tell me how I can move the robot? or is there another teleop packages for moving p3dx?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33778/p3dx-gazebo-problem-with-fuerte/) by [musti](https://answers.ros.org/users/2364/musti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that the p3dx package has not been upgraded to Fuerte yet. In Fuerte, Gazebo was upgraded to version 1.0, so there have been a number of changes. If the p3dx package has not been modified, it very well might not work with Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0